# Share gitignored files across team

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I recently added typings files to my project so that I get intellisense in VS Code for libraries such as Angular, D3, Underscore, etc.

So my changes in this branch were adding a `typings/` folder with relevant typings files, adding `typings.json`, and adding `jsconfig.json`. I also added each of these to my `.gitignore`. So my diff only shows the `.gitignore` changes. If I merge this into remote master, when other team members pull it down will they have the `typings` folder, `typings.json`, and `jsconfig.json`. I want them to have access to this so they also get intellisense if using VS Code, but I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly.

Comment: Right, let me get this straight, you _want_ the `typings` folder and its content to be shared with others, right? Why did you add them to `.gitignore` afterwards?

Comment: What is the reason for ignoring these files?

Comment: @big_water, looks like I was overthinking this, no need to ignore after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they will not pull down the files that you listed in gitignore because they will not be pushed up when you commit and push.  They will only pull down the changes to the gitignore file.  The only way they would get the new "typings" folder and files is if you removed them from your gitignore and checked them into git and then merge your changes into master.

Comment: Thanks! So to ignore them I should make 2 commits; one to add the typings folder and files, and a second to ignore them?

Comment: What is the reason for ignoring them?  Are they user specific?